# MATLAB cell2mat unique error cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I created a cell Array like this

```
A{1} = {'aa','b','d','aa'};
A{2} = {'c','d','aa'};
A{3} = {'bb','aa','bb','aa'};
```

now I wanna find the unique words

```
b=cell2mat(A)
unique(b)
```

but I get this Error: `Error using cell2mat (line 52) Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects`.

I'm fairly new to matlab. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you want `a,b,c,d` or `aa,b,bb,c,d`?

Comment: Odd, your code works in octave, apparently a matlab "extension" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A{1} = {'aa','b','d','aa'};
A{2} = {'c','d','aa'};
A{3} = {'bb','aa','bb','aa'};

unique([A{:}])
```

There you go. The `{:}`, `(:)` and `[]` operators are very useful in MATLAB. Get comfortable using them.